# WPF Webbrowser Control added JavaScript code and Object.freeze function is unsupported

Tags: javascript, c#, wpf

I am adding JavaScript code to a WebBrowser Control in my `WPF` App. In my JavaScript code I use the function `Object.freeze()`, which will get me the following error, when I run the app.

[image: Script error message]

My *.xaml* with the WebBrowser control looks like this.

```
<Window x:Class="TestWPFApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWPFApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <WebBrowser x:Name="ProgressBarWeb" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="300" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And my HTML and JavaScript code is added with the `NavigateToString()` function

```
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   //Js Code is a extract but the effect is the same
   var html = "<html><head><script>" +
               "var platformtypes = {"Attr1": 0, "Attr2": 1};" +
               "Object.freeze(platformtypes);" +
               "</script></head><body></body></html>"
   ProgressBarWeb.NavigateToString(html);
}
```

My question are now:

1. Which interpreter does Visual Studio 2017 uses to Interpret JavaScript code?
2. Is there a possibility to change/update the Interpreter?
3. Or do I miss something else?

Comment: You are getting About:Blank which indicates the script is trying to navigate to another webpage.  You want to execute the JavaScript Freeze and pass a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by using the [CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp).

In `.xaml` I added

```
<ContentControl x:Name="browserContainer" Height="300" Width="300" Content=""/>
```

and in the code I use

```
var html = "<html><head><script>" +
           "var platformtypes = {"Attr1": 0, "Attr2": 1};" +
           "Object.freeze(platformtypes);" +
           "</script></head><body></body></html>";
var base64EncodedHtml = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html));
var browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser()
{
   Address = "data:text/html;base64," + base64EncodedHtml,
   RenderProcessMessageHandler = new RenderProcessMessageHandler()
};

browserContainer.Content = browser;
```